# Print out three dimensional array and getting the combined integer value

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I´m trying to create a 3 dimensional array which should have three horizontal boxes which two rows and 3 columns in each. As it is the output get me two vertical boxes with 3 rows and 3 columns, I have tried to change the integers around but it seems to just get me in deeper trouble.

And on top of this I´ve been trying to add all the integers in the array to get and print out the mean/average value but I can´t really find/understand how to do this.

```
int[][][] ett= {{ {10,12,14}, {16,18,20}, {22,24,26} },
                { {11,13,15}, {17,19,21}, {23,25,27} } };   
//want this to print out as it looks, three "boxes" with two rows and three columns

for (int i= 0; i<ett.length;i++){
    for (int j= 0; j<ett[i].length ;j++){
        for (int k=0; k<ett[i][j].length;k++){

        System.out.print(ett[i][j][k]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();

}
int medel=0;

//medel = all integers in array added, 10+12+14...
// divide medel with number of integers in array (18)


System.out.println("Medelvärdet: "+medel);


}//main
```

Answer (score 2):

You only have to get rid of one `println` :

```
for (int i= 0; i<ett.length;i++){
    for (int j= 0; j<ett[i].length ;j++){
        for (int k=0; k<ett[i][j].length;k++){
            System.out.print(ett[i][j][k]+" ");
        }
        // System.out.println(); remove this println
    }
    System.out.println();

}
```

and you'll get this :

```
10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 
11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27
```

You might want to add spaces between the blocks :

```
for (int i= 0; i<ett.length;i++){
    for (int j= 0; j<ett[i].length ;j++){
        for (int k=0; k<ett[i][j].length;k++){
            System.out.print(ett[i][j][k]+" ");
        }
        System.out.print("  ");
    }
    System.out.println();

}
```

which will give you this:

```
10 12 14   16 18 20   22 24 26   
11 13 15   17 19 21   23 25 27
```